# C# / PHP => Upload file as Base64 and write it on disk

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest

**What i want to do:**

I need to do a POST to a PHP Service using HttpWebRequest, and upload an image file as a Base64(can't change this) string along with other parameters and write the Base64 data in a database.

**What i do:**

- So far i am able to upload the Base64 data representing an image
- PHP side do receive the data and write it to the database

**What doesn't work**

- When i am trying to read the Base64 data from the database and write it on the disk, it write the file but i am unable to open the file as an image

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need check out: 1. blob field will enough space for store your encoded base64 text; 2. when you write down to disk, do you decode this?

Comment: How can we help you if you don't post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually in the Base64 string where in C# there was some '+' symbols and on the PHP side the '+' were removed for some reasons.

I just added the following line:

```
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
```

Now all work fine.

Thanks!